# I want to insert this symbol(') in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-insert

In a sql Table , i have a field as Height and i want to insert the height as 5'6'' that is 5 feet and 6 inches. How can i do this?

While using the simple insert command it throws an error. Whats is the possible way to overcome this?

Comment: Can u try putting value as "5'6'"?   Put it inside double quote

Comment: Next time, read the error. *Sometimes*, it gives you the clues you need to work it out...

Answer (score 7):

If you are doing it directly on MySQL Server, double the single quote and it will work. Example

```
INSERT INTO tableName (height) VALUES ('5''6"')
```

But on front-end, use *PreparedStatements* for this.

Comment: Yes, there is no reason to not use prepared statements, and too many reasons to actually use them over regular queries. In fact, using prepared statements should be your standard procedure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want escape the `'`, just put ' twice (`''`).

```
insert into tes values ('5''6''''');
```

Work in `MySQL`, `Oracle` and `MSSQL`

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

```
Insert into table_name(column_name) values('5'||''''||'6'||'"');
```

Answer (score 0):

All symbol like `;`, `'`, `<`, `>`, and others must be inserted with backslash before:

```
\'
\>
\;
```

In your case:

```
INSERT INTO tableName (height) VALUES ('5\'\'6\"')
```